# Scikit-learn: What are the labels returned by MeanShift fit_predict()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, computer-vision, mean-shift

I am trying to segment a colour image using the Mean-Shift algorithm using scikit-learn. There is something I would like to know about the MeanShift fit_predict() function. In the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html#sklearn.cluster.MeanShift) for the MeanShift algorithm, it states that fit_predict() performs clustering on X and returns cluster labels.

What exactly are the cluster labels? Are they the labels for all the clusters the algorithm found, or is there a label for each data sample returned? Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a label returned for each training example. It is a combination of the fit() and the predict() function.